# Jinja template as variable value

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to use [jinja](/questions/tagged/jinja) template as value for [ansible.builtin.lineinfile module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) in role task.

```sh
named
├── tasks
│   ├── config.yml
│   ├── main.yml
├── templates
│   ├── option.ji2
│   ├── view.ji2
```

```yaml
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: "{{ test_dir }}{{ named_config_file['path'] }}"
    regex: "{{ item['key'] }}"
    line: "{% set option = item %}{% include 'option.ji2' %}"
    validate: named-checkconf %s
  loop: "{{ named_options | dict2items }}"
```

Unfortunately ansible throws **TemplateNotFound** error:

```sh
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: option.ji2
```

Using relative or absolute path to template doesn't help.

The same template included in `view.ji2` works:

```
{% for option in item['options'] | dict2items %}
{% if option is mapping %}
{% include 'option.ji2' %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In other role playbook there is simple Jinja template (without include) that also works:

```yaml
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    key:
      "{% if item[1]['key'] is match('ssh-.{256}') %}\
      {{ item[1]['key'] }}\
      {% else %}\
      {{ lookup('file', item[1]['key'], errors='ignore') }}\
      {% endif %}"
    user: "{{ item[0]['name'] }}"
    state: "{{ item[1]['state'] | default(omit, true) }}"
  loop: "{{ user_accounts | subelements('authorized_keys', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

Any ideas why [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible) can't find/use template `option.ji2`?

Comment: Try adding the path to the file.

Comment: Already tried some combinations, including the ones listed below, but still no luck.

`templates/option.ji2`

`../templates/option.ji2`

`/home/ansible/.ansible/roles/named/templates/option.ji2`

Answer (score 0):

Workaround/solution is to use *template* lookup.

```yaml
ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
  path: "{{ test_dir }}{{ named_config_file['path'] }}"
  regex: "{{ item['key'] }}"
  line: "{{ lookup('template','option.ji2') }}"
  validate: named-checkconf %s
loop: "{{ named_options | dict2items }}"
```